# Is there more concise way to specify OpenAPI @Operation response class?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

In migrating from Springboot 2 to Springboot 3, we of course have to change our swagger annotations from Swagger 2 to OpenAPI.
In our controller classes, we have a ton of endpoint methods that start out decorated with just one line like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create Employee", response = EmployeeResponse.class)
```

But with the new open API spec, the closest syntax I could find to replace that is

```
@Operation( summary = "create Employee", 
   responses = { 
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success", 
            content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            schema = @Schema(implementation = EmployeeResponse.class)))
    }
```

Isn't there a more concise way to provide the equivalent response class without all the extra repeated boilerplate noise?

Hopefully some way to just specify the class name like before with as little extra as possible. After all, if that extra boilerplate code wasn't necessary before, it shouldn't be necessary now

Comment: "little extra as possible" : tried "the defaults" (omitting any openapi annotations)!?

Comment: @xerx593 yeah that seems to be the best solution actually

Comment: @xerx593 if you can copy your comment into an answer, I can accept it